# Changing table row borders query

Tags: html, css

For some reason my tr borders aren't showing internally, I have no idea why and have never had an issue with it? Its meant to be a dynamic table where an x and a y value can be placed within an input and it then creates it.

html:

```
<body>

    <label id="h">x :</label>
    <input type="number" id="width">
    <label id="w">y :</label>
    <input type="number" id="length">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
    <table style="width:40%" id="table">
    </table>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="TableGenerator.js"></script>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
    background-color:#929caa;
 }

#w{
    color:white;
  }
#h{
    color:white;
}
table{
    background-color:#d5dce5 ;
    border-collapse: separate;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: black;
}
tr{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS:  (Column insertion is sill in process)

```
 var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
 submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
    InsertNewRow();
    InsertNewCol();

  })


   function InsertNewRow () {

        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("width").value; i++) {
            var table = document.getElementById ("table");
            var row = table.insertRow (-1);
            row.className = "row";
            row.innerHTML = "New Row";
        }}
   function InsertNewCol(){

        }
```

Comment: Where is the table in your html?

Comment: Amended, it was cut out..

Comment: What is your TableGenerator.js producing? Can we see the produced code that reproduces the style issue?

Comment: Updated, I am currently still in the process of making the columns js.

Comment: If you want celled table, add border to td as well, it'll work
or use border-collapse: collapse as @Bhuvan suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` border works only with `border-collapse: collapse` not with `separate`. So try to change `border-collapse` value to `collpase` in `table` css

```css
table {
  background-color: #d5dce5;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: black;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-collapse: collapse;` it will show the lines between the rows.